# Land Rover Freelander 2 - Bad MPG

Tags: maintenance, diesel, fuel-consumption, service, freelander

2007 Freelander 2

Was having what I consider bad MPG for a diesel, averaging around 23-24mpg

Initially thought it needs a service, so lots of money later for a full service which would have included all filters and the MPG is no different.

Anywhere else I should look or does 24mpg sound about right?

You should note I don't do many miles, my daily commute is only 9 miles.
On a long motorway at 60mph I can only just get 40mpg

Comment: Doing the service is the first step so good. Now you need to check injectors, fuelling etc. If you have a good local garage them get them to check the emissions as a first step. After that it is remove and test injectors for pattern. leak off etc - usually best done by specialists. However, do check the stated mileage on sites like Parkers etc you may not be too far out...

Comment: Have you checked when the haldex oil and filter were last changed?

Answer (score 1):

24 does sound a bit low. The official combined figure for a Freelander 2 Diesel is 42MPG, Honest John report a real-world figure of 31-35 - Of course, if your 9 mile commute is all stop-start urban driving then you can expect to get poor economy, as a Diesel SUV is not exactly designed for that! However I'd expect you to be seeing 45+ on a motorway cruise.

Are you going by the trip computer or by fill-to-fill measurement? Trip computers can sometimes be wildly inaccurate.

As Mike says, check the fuelling system, particularly the injectors, and the emissions - they should be able to see instantly if you have a lot of unburnt fuel coming out.

Comment: I've been using the trip computer, I'll do the maths next time I put fuel in. It's recently passed the MOT is running well and no visible emissions from the exhaust, I'll check the maths first before doing anything else as it seems to be running well